# DataSourceSecurityFilter Eclipse Scout

Tags: eclipse, jaas, eclipse-scout

I am working on a server-client program using the Eclipse Scout framework. I have Java experience, but my expierence regarding Tomcat is not existing.

I want to write an application which asks for my login information. Using the DataSourceSecurityFilter i want to autherise a user in the program (reading his username and password from the database). My server config.ini looks like this:

```
### Service Runtime Configuration


org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.services.common.file.RemoteFileService#rootPath=/Users/wgvanveen/Documents/workspace/ledenbeheer.server/j2ee/ear/war/WEB-INF/remotefiles

### Servlet Filter Runtime Configuration
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#active=false
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#realm=ledenbeheer Development
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.BasicSecurityFilter#users=admin\=manager,allen\=allen,blake\=blake
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#active=false
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#realm=TEST APPLICATION
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcDriverName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcMappingName=jdbc:mysql://localhost/Leden 
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcUsername=root
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#jdbcPassword=root
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#selectUserPass=SELECT LOWER(Gebruikersnaam) FROM Gebruikers WHERE LOWER(gebruikersnaam)=? AND PASSWORD=?
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.AnonymousSecurityFilter#active=true
```

I have added to the server plugin the following:

```
<filter
            aliases="/process"
            class="org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter"
            ranking="40">
      </filter>
```

I have no clue why this doesn't work. I have followed the instructions from : http://wiki.eclipse.org/Scout/Concepts/Security

I am running Eclipse Juno with Scout 3.8

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the wrong filter is active.

org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.DataSourceSecurityFilter#active=false
org.eclipse.scout.http.servletfilter.security.AnonymousSecurityFilter#active=true

Try to activate the data source filter and deactivate the anonymous filter. If it doesn't work, I suggest you post the question at the official scout forum at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=thread&frm_id=174.